# How to define the coverage of my nutch crawl?

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I've been collecting/crawling a website over the last two weeks. I've used the `crawl` command setting `100` iterations. The process has just finished. How can I know the coverage of the data crawled? I really don't expect an exact number, but I'd really like to know *approximately* how much information remains un-crawled in the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Jorge. Based on what you've said:

> Nutch has no idea of how big/small is the website(s) you're crawling

So, there's no way to calculate that unless you know the size of the website in advance.

Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

You question is a bit ambiguous, if you're trying to get how much data of the entire website you've already crawled this is a hard problem, Nutch has no idea of how big/small is the website(s) you're crawling. You said that you have done 100 iterations, using default settings in the `bin/crawl` script this means that on each iteration Nutch it is fetching a maximum of 50 000 URLs (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/src/bin/crawl#L117), but this doesn't mean that your website doesn't have more URLs, just means that this is a configuration on Nutch, and perhaps Nutch haven't even discovered all the URLs. On each iteration Nutch could discover new URLs making the process incremental.

What you can do is execute the `bin/nutch readdb` command passing the `-stats` parameter, something like:

```
$ bin/nutch readdb crawl/crawldb -stats
```

This should bring an output similar to:

```
CrawlDb statistics start: crawl/crawldb
Statistics for CrawlDb: crawl/crawldb
TOTAL urls: 575
retry 0:    569
retry 1:    6
min score:  0.0
avg score:  0.0069252173
max score:  1.049
status 1 (db_unfetched):    391
status 2 (db_fetched):  129
status 3 (db_gone): 53
status 4 (db_redir_temp):   1
status 5 (db_redir_perm):   1
CrawlDb statistics: done
```

With this info you could know the total amount of URLs discovered and how much of this have been fetched, along with some more useful information.